# how to join the tables in spring hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have 3 tables, how can i join the query in hibernate

appointments

```
id schedule_date subject  user_id doctor_id
1  23-12-2016    Fever    1           21
2  24-12-2016    headache 2           22
```

prescriptions

```
id appointment_id status
1  1              1
2  2              2
```

user_medications

```
id prescription_id drug_id status
1  1                1       1
2  1                2       1
```

Now i need the result of the users drugs

if condition user_id = 1 & status = 1

i will get the following result, for the following sql.

```
SELECT um.id, p.id as prescription_id, um.drug_id, um.status FROM `appointments` a
LEFT JOIN `prescriptions` p ON a.id = p.appointment_id
LEFT JOIN `user_medications` um ON p.id = um.prescription_id
WHERE a.patient_id = 30 and um.id != null group by um.id

id prescription_id drug_id status
1  1                1       1
2  1                2       1
```

Here is my Entity classes:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "appointments")
public class Appointment extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1320944167976543131L;

    @Column(name = "schedule_date")
    private Date scheduleDate;

    @Column(name = "patient_id")
    private Long patientId;

    @Column(name = "doctor_id")
    private Long doctorId;

    @Column(name = "subject")
    private String subject;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Doctor doctor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;


    public Date getScheduleDate() {
        return scheduleDate;
    }

    public void setScheduleDate(Date scheduleDate) {
        this.scheduleDate = scheduleDate;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public Doctor getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Prescription Entity:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "prescriptions")
public class Prescription extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6316326407564010588L;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "appointment_id")
    private Long appointmentId;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Appointment appointment;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prescription")
    private Set<UserMedication> userMedications = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "is_self_declared")
    private Boolean isSelfDeclared;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }



    public Long getAppointmentId() {
        return appointmentId;
    }

    public void setAppointmentId(Long appointmentId) {
        this.appointmentId = appointmentId;
    }


    public Boolean getIsSelfDeclared() {
        return isSelfDeclared;
    }

    public void setIsSelfDeclared(Boolean isSelfDeclared) {
        this.isSelfDeclared = isSelfDeclared;
    }

    public Appointment getAppointment() {
        return appointment;
    }

    public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        this.appointment = appointment;
    }

    public Set<UserMedication> getUserMedications() {
        return userMedications;
    }

    public void setUserMedications(Set<UserMedication> userMedications) {
        this.userMedications = userMedications;
    }

    public Doctor getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }
}
```

User Medication entity:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "prescription_medications")
public class UserMedication extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3853355501806579362L;

    @Column(name = "prescription_id")
    private Long prescriptionId;

    @Column(name = "drug_id")
    private Long drugId;

    @Column(name = "dosage")
    private String dosage;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "prescription_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Prescription prescription;



    public Long getPrescriptionId() {
        return prescriptionId;
    }

    public void setPrescriptionId(Long prescriptionId) {
        this.prescriptionId = prescriptionId;
    }

    public Long getDrugId() {
        return drugId;
    }

    public void setDrugId(Long drugId) {
        this.drugId = drugId;
    }

    public String getDosage() {
        return dosage;
    }

    public void setDosage(String dosage) {
        this.dosage = dosage;
    }


}
```

This is the query, i tried using native query =  true

```
@Query(value = "select a.id as appointment_id, um.id as user_medication_id, um.drug_id from appointments a "
            + "left join prescriptions p on a.id = p.appointment_id "
            + "left join user_medications um on p.id = um.prescription_id "
            + "where a.patient_id = :userId and um.is_active = :userMedicationStatus and um.id is not null",
            nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserMedication> findUserMedications(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("userMedicationStatus") Boolean userMedicationStatus, Pageable pageRequest);
```

I am getting he following error,

```
'userMedicationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.InvalidJpaQueryMethodException: Cannot use native queries with dynamic sorting and/or pagination in method public abstract org.springframework
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to return a `Page<T>` when specifying `nativeQuery=true`.

If you provide HQL/JPQL instead and remove `nativeQuery=true`, you can fetch paged results with no problem; otherwise you'll need to return a `List<UserMedication>` instead for native queries.

Your query translated to HQL to return `UserMediciation` entities would be:

```
SELECT um FROM UserMedication um
JOIN Prescription p 
WHERE p.userId = :userId
AND um.active = :userMediciationStatus
```

I didn't see the `is_active` column defined so I assumed it is defined in the `BaseEntity` as a property called `active`.  You'll need to adjust the HQL accordingly based on your needs.  I also elected not to apply `JOIN FETCH` semantics between `UserMedication` and both `Prescription` and `Appointment`.  If you find you need those relations fetched as part of the result-set for  the UI, you'll need to adjust that accordingly.  But this should definitely get you started.

Comment: can i get some documentation reference to do in HQL/JPQL for the above

Comment: Added HQL representation.  As you can see the HQL is a bit cleaner to read than raw SQL too.

Comment: cant i use @Query annotation for this type of functionality, ,ike this...@Query(value = "SELECT um FROM UserMedication JOIN Prescription p WHERE p.userId = :userId AND um.active = :userMediciationStatus")
 Page<UserMedication> findUserMedications(@Param("userId") Long userId,
   @Param("userMediciationStatus") int[] userMediciationStatus, Pageable pageRequest);

Comment: Sorry @javailike there was a small typo.  Can you retry, my apologies.